# Jtext field to listen without pressing enter

Tags: java, sql, swing, ms-access-2007

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Save extends JPanel {

Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

String TrailerName;
String BlockName;
String LocationName;
String newline = "\n";
String text;

JComboBox<?> TrailerList;
JComboBox<?> BlockList;
JComboBox<?> LocationList;
JTextField textField;
JTextArea textArea;

public Save() {
     super(new BorderLayout());

     textField = new JTextField(20);

     textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
     textArea.setEditable(false);
     textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  text = textField.getText();
                  textArea.append(text + newline);
                  textField.selectAll();

                  textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                  System.out.println("Comment: " + text);
                 }
              });

    String[] Trailer = { "A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "Please select a Trailer" };
    String[] Block = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Please select a Block" };
    String[] Location = { "Door A3", "Door B2", "Door C4", "Door D2", "Door E9", "Please select a Location" };

    TrailerList = new JComboBox<Object>(Trailer);
    TrailerList.setSelectedIndex(5);
    TrailerList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                 TrailerName = (String) TrailerList.getSelectedItem();
                 System.out.println("Trailer: " + TrailerName);
        }
    });

    BlockList = new JComboBox<Object>(Block);
    BlockList.setSelectedIndex(5);
    BlockList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                   BlockName = (String) BlockList.getSelectedItem();
                   System.out.println("Block: " + BlockName);
   }
```

});

```
    LocationList = new JComboBox<Object>(Location);
    LocationList.setSelectedIndex(5);
    LocationList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                   LocationName = (String) LocationList.getSelectedItem();
                   System.out.println("Location: " + LocationName);
   }
```

});

```
    JButton buttonSave = new JButton("Save");
    add(buttonSave);
    buttonSave.setActionCommand("Save");
    add(buttonSave);
    buttonSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             String action = evt.getActionCommand();
                if (action.equals("Save")) {
                    System.out.println("Button pressed!");
                    try {
                        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
                        Class.forName(driver);
                        String db = "jdbc:odbc:TTracking";
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);

                    DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
                    System.out.println("Server name: " +
           meta.getDatabaseProductName());
                    System.out.println("Server version: " +
           meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                    System.out.println("");

                    System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");

                    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO TrailerLocation (Trailer, Block, Location, Day, SetTime, Comment) " +
                        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW(), ?)");

                        st.setString(1, TrailerName);
                        st.setString(2, BlockName);
                        st.setString(3, LocationName);
                        st.setString(4, text);
                        st.addBatch();

                        st.executeBatch();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inserted record into the table: "
                                + "\nTrailer : " + TrailerName
                                + "\nBlock : " + BlockName
                                + "\nLocation : " + LocationName
                                + "\nComment : " + text);

                       }catch(SQLException se){
                      //Handle errors for JDBC
                      se.printStackTrace();
                       }catch(Exception e1){
                      //Handle errors for Class.forName
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                      }finally{
                      //finally block used to close resources
                      try{
                            if(st!=null)
                            con.close();
                      }catch(SQLException se){
                      }// do nothing
                         try{
                         if(con!=null)
                         con.close();
                         }catch(SQLException se){
                         se.printStackTrace();
                         }//end finally try
                    }//end try
                         System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                   }}
                 });

    add(TrailerList, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(BlockList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(LocationList, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(buttonSave,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Save");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);


    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new Save();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

1. For a form I am creating I have a text field for people to add comments but the issue is for the comment to save you need to press the enter button is there a way to do it without pressing the enter button?
2. Tried Doc-listener and Action listener but could not get code to work

Comment: Use a "save" button, collect all the information and save it in single step

Comment: the form does have a save button but does not recognize what is in the text field unless I press enter which I want to avoid

Comment: So how do you know when the user has finished typing?

Comment: `DocumentListener` is the solution you're looking for (if you don't want to press enter or have some kind of save action).  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: okay I will add the rest of the code now

Comment: You can use the mouseExited() method of a MouseListener.

Comment: would that work where once the you click elsewhere it will save what is stored in the textfield

Comment: If that's what you want, then use a FocusListener and save the content in your listener's focusLost() method.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is, remove the usage of variable "text" and directly use textField.getText() ,but to update the text area you still need to use a DocumentListener.

ex:

```
st.setString(4, textField.getText());
```

But in design perspective this should be improved, my advise is to use a Model to maintain the GUI data status,
you can use beansbinding to synchronize GUI components with model.
once user click on save button, then that model should be submitted to some other class to handle the save function.